# Send data only related to that line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following dynamically generated form:

```js
var data = [
   {Id: "1", },
   {Id: "2", },
   {Id: "3", },
   {Id: "4", },
   {Id: "5", },
   {Id: "6", },
];

$(document).on('click', '.dad-pagamento', function() {

  var linha = ``;
  for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {

   linha += `<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="row g-3 instarefa">
             <div class="col-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id_tareff[]" value="${data[x].Id}">
             </div>
             <div class="col-7">
              <label for="obsposic" class="form-label">Observações </label>
              <textarea rows="3" class="form-control aarea" name="obsposic[]"></textarea>
             </div>
             <div class="col-1">
              <button type="button" class="btn-wide btn btn-primary"  onclick="reg_tarefa();"> TRATADO <i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-paper-plane"></i></button>
             </div>
             </form>
             <hr class="linha"/>`;
   
   $(".pagmfalta").html(linha);
   $('#minhaDiv1').show();
   
   }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pixeden-stroke-7-icon@1.2.3/pe-icon-7-stroke/dist/pe-icon-7-stroke.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info dad-pagamento" style="float: right; margin-right: 5%; margin-top: 4%;"><i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-search"></i> Consultar </button>

<section id="s1">
  <div style="display:none" id="minhaDiv1">
        <div class="row pagmfalta">

        </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

So far so good. My problem is now sending the values ​​to php to insert in the database. I'm doing it like this:

```
function reg_tarefa()
{  
var id_tareff = [];
$("input[name='id_tareff[]']").each(function() {id_tareff.push(this.value)});

var obsposic = [];
$("textarea[name^='obsposic[]']").each(function() {obsposic.push($(this).val())});

var dadosajax = {
'id_tareff[]' : id_tareff,
'obsposic[]' : obsposic
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'regtarefa.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: dadosajax,
    success: function(result2){ 

    }
  });
}
```

For example, I want to click on the second button, where Id=2 and only send data regarding that id. And as I am doing it sends the data of all the ids. Can you help?

Comment: Use `onclick="reg_tarefa(this)"` and then have the function use the argument to navigate to the current elements.

Comment: @barmar Can you put an example of how the function uses the (this) argument to navigate to the current elements

Comment: Don't you know how to use methods like `$(element).closest("form")` and `.find()` to find the elements inside it?

Comment: @barmar I'll look into it to see if I can get what I want.

Comment: @barmar Can I ask to put an example with my code?

Comment: Show what you tried and I'll help you fix it. I'm not going to do it for you.

Comment: @barmar The problem is that I still haven't found anything to put into practice

Comment: I told you the basic building blocks. What part of it don't you understand? You can't just expect randoms on the Internet to do your coding for you, you have to learn how to do it on your own.

Comment: @barmar I'm trying to replace this line `function reg_task()` with this `$('.reg_task').closest(".instatask").find("")`, but I don't know what to put in find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the button to pass itself as the argument to `reg_tarefa`: `onclick="reg_tarefa(this);"`.

Then change the function to use DOM navigation relative to the button to find the inputs in the same form.

```js
function reg_tarefa(element) {
  let form = $(element).closest("form");
  
  var id_tareff = [];
  form.find("input[name='id_tareff[]']").each(function() {
    id_tareff.push(this.value)
  });

  var obsposic = [];
  form.find$("textarea[name^='obsposic[]']").each(function() {
    obsposic.push($(this).val())
  });

  var dadosajax = {
    'id_tareff[]': id_tareff,
    'obsposic[]': obsposic
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: 'regtarefa.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: dadosajax,
    success: function(result2) {
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand, I was not understanding how to use find